# UITableView Flicker Effect

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, flicker

There are about 100 cells displayed in UITableView. So , when I scroll down or up too fast I see a flicker effect over UITableView.

I have also re-used the cells and I am not using reloadData in my code, but still I see flicker effect.

The content that I am displaying in each cell is only text.

I have also gone through this thread but did not found useful [UITableView section headers are blank and flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023841/uitableview-section-headers-are-blank-and-flickering).

Comment: You should try to see if this is the case on a device first. The simulator is just that, it tries to simulate but it's no proof.

Answer (score 0):

I think with a number of cells I noticed my old iphone 3g struggle every now and then when i was flicking for a quick scroll to the bottom.